# Trying to play a sound from a stream; file started as .mp3, then byte[] array, then stream.. Why would it not work?

Tags: c#, audio

so i have a byte stream: i can save the file w/ a .mp3 extension and it plays fine, but what would you do to do a live playback?  Its actually an mp3, but streamed so it's in a byte array.  You can save it with a .mp3 extension and it'll playback fine, why wouldn't it play from a stream if it's an mp3 file to begin with? How do i play it from a stream.

```
            byte[] d1 = mywave
            //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\" + t.ToString() + ".mp3", d1);
            MemoryStream buff = new MemoryStream(d1);
            SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(buff);
            sp.Play();
```

throws The wave header is corrupt. / InvalidOperationException

So how would i create an audio header on the stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can Just Change the 4 first  Bytes by the the code of Audio files in the beginning of the  file !

.. if that what you need .. good luck

Comment: it began as an mp3, was put into bytes why would it have a bad header?
is there a formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't 'played' much with it, but could be as it's mp3...

```
The SoundPlayer class cannot play other file types, such as .wma or .mp3.    
If you want to play other file types, you can use the Windows Media Player control
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: it does play .mp3 i already stated that.  It's a header format exception problem, since a stream probably is simply bytes, not a file: it's not going to have a header.

Comment: it plays `where` ? - I doubt the SoundPlayer can play it if they say so (all up to 4.5). Mp3 may be fine but from some other player.

Comment: the 'header error' you're getting is likely because it can't recognize it. There may be some hack there but I doubt it. At least I have no idea of it.

Comment: or use similar code, just stream the '.wav' file and you'll see if the code works or is the file

Answer (score 0):

The SoundPlayer class plays WAV files, not MP3s. There are several libraries that will play MP3s, see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/csharpgeneral/thread/2a797b38-e22c-457f-be0f-27a9d54a3e2c) MSDN forum post.